# save/download xml file when click on the download button

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm generating a xml file using javascript,now i want to save/download this generated xml file whn I click the download button.Actually I set,

```
document.location= 'data:Application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(xml_content);
```

but it is opening in the same page or new tab...download is not starting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much of option to try it right now.
Could you just try:

```
document.open= 'data:Application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(xml_content);
```